Speed up mass inserts for SQL Server without direct application access?
I have an application in a proprietary programming language. The database access is handles via ODBC connections to an SQL Server 2019. There is one use case in the application in which prepared statements are used to dump thousands of inserts into the same table.
Unfortunately I cannot change the inserts themselves as the application's object relationship mapping handles the inserts and that is a "black box".
The only options I have is to provide the ideal environment for these inserts to thrive.
The layout of the table is as follows:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CostTable](
    [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TimeEntry] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserEntry] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GUID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Costs1] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Costs2] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Costs3] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[Costs4] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[Costs5] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[Costs6] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[Costs7] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CostTable] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [GUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

There are also a few indexes applied to this table.
Unfortunately I cannot change the format of the primary key and the value itself is created by the application. It is an alphanumeric key. A numeric key would most likely be better but I cannot do that.
Would it help to turn off check constraints and turn them on after all the inserts?
Are there any other options available?
Is there something I can adjust in the ODBC driver? I am using the SQL Server Native Client 11.0. The ODBC driver can be changed as required.

There is not much you can do to speed up inserts. Sometimes for one-off mass inserts, overhead can be reduced by dropping or disabling all indexes and constraints, performing the inserts, and then rebuilding/re-enabling those prior indexes and constraints, but I don't think that would work for your situation. Using a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type instead of VARCHAR would be preferred for a GUID. That might reduce some overhead difference, but is not huge. The real work is allocating space for the new rows by expanding and/or splitting pages in the clustered index, and repeating for other indexes.

Thank you for the reply. The type of the column cannot be changed as the key value is coming from the application. Is there a way to reduce the page alterations or do it more predictively?

I'm not seeing anything obvious. The GUID primary key is non-clustered, which might actually be a good thing with lots of inserts. The inserts from your app are beyond your control, but if the app is performing one insert statement per row (vs multi-row inserts), that is a major contributor to the performance problems. All I can think of is throwing more hardware at it - faster storage (SSDs) would be my first choice, more memory perhaps, I don't think more processors would help with what may be single-threaded operations. I am not the expert though. Others might have more useful suggestions.

Is tthere any chance you can wrap up your INSERT operations in transactions of a few thousand rows each? The way SQL Server handles transactions, that will save a whole mess of time over individually auto-committing  each INSERT.

Don't think a lot can be done, but 1k inserts shouldn't take that long? Get better hardware perhaps? You can perhaps put the table on different filegroup with faster disks but not sure it's worth the hassle. How long does it takes today?

You could try lowering the FILLFACTOR on any indexes with the GUID, including PK_CostTable, to reduce the number of page splits. Maybe start with 80%. This probably will not make much difference as PK_CostTable is nonclustered.

You can modify the configuration & structure of the database & table to speed up the same application process.
Checking
The application might calculate some values from other tables with some queries before writing to the table. These queries might need to be optimized.
Before bulk load process investigate what the application send to Sql Server with Sql Profiler. Then look which steps takes longer
Bulk Load optimization
If these is a one time jop or a scheduled job then to optimize the inserting speed.
1.) Take a full backup.  To release the allocated space of transaction logs.
2.) Change recovery model to Simple.
3.) Check and Increase the Autogrowth size of your log & database files. 512, 1024 MB like the picture below.
This will decrease the database - transaction log file's growth frequency.
After scheduled process you can set to an ideal disk value. Lets say 256 MB.

4.) Disable all indexes, except Primary Key.
5.) Disable all constraint with no check.
6.) Within Sql Server dont put every thing in the same disk/driver.
Separete into data files into own, transaction log files into own. If it is possible add temp db files in to seperate dedicated fast disks.
